# WP-Members / How to update value of radio button value?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WP-Members. And I'm using `wp_update_user` function to update value.
When I try to update the "text" value, it is updated. Like this.

```
$test = array ( 'ID' => $id,'first_name' => $first_name);
```

But, when it comes to update the value of "radio", it didn't work.

```
$test = array ( 'ID' => $id,'plan' => $plan);
```

$plan is a string value

[setting of the "plan"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJIGa.png)

How can I update the radio button value?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_update_user()` only updates WordPress native fields. If you have a radio field in your form, then that would certainly be a custom field not native to WP.  Any custom field is a user meta field and must be updated with [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/):

`update_user_meta( $id, 'plan', $plan );`

Note that this would be true of any field that is not a native WP field (i.e. any custom fields you added in WP-Members, or using any other method).